# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException In Camera generated file

Tags: android, kotlin

In some of android device while generating file for camera simple date formatting is not working properly.

below is the code using to generate time stamp

```
val timeStamp: String =
            SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
```

below is the code for generating file

```
val storageDir: File? = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        return File.createTempFile(
            "JPEG_${timeStamp}_", /* prefix */
            ".jpg", /* suffix */
            storageDir /* directory */
        ).apply {
            // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
            capturedPhotoPath = absolutePath
        }
```

below is the crash getting in fire base but i am not able to reproduce it

**Caused by java.net.URISyntaxException
Illegal character in path at index 60: file:////data/user/0/com.conduent.bw/cache/images/2020-09-25 MW.jpg**

Comment: Which is the character at index 60?

Comment: empty space 
date formater i have given "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss" but some how in crash 2020-09-25 MW value is coming

Comment: It is impossible that getExternalFilesDir delivers the path mentioned in that exception. Code and exception do not match.

Comment: Why are you posting code for file creation and that exception? You could simply tell that the time stamp formatting does not work as expected. That is all. Concentrate on that.